# Facebook API post in group through linked Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am facing an issue, using Facebook api, i am able to post in a group using User Access Token and as a user. But i want to post in a group as a Page, i have linked page with that group. But it seems the whole process is not working when using Page access token instead of User.

Using this endpoint for testing.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/{group-id}/feed?access_token={access-token}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was fixed my allowing permission while getting user access token.
Permission includes:

1. publish_actions
2. publish_pages
3. manage_pages
4. user_managed_group

Comment: Hi, can you shed some light regarding the flow?
1. get user access token
2. asking for the manage_pages permission
3. get the page access token via the Graph API
4. use the page access token to post to the group id.

Is that correct?